# Java illegal start of type in correct project

Tags: java, compilation

I have a Java application which I cannot launch

All error message of the type:

```
illegal start of type
HashMap<String, Double> simScoreTable = new HashMap<>();
                                                    ^

illegal start of type
HashMap<String, Double> simScoreTable = new HashMap<>();
                                                    ^
```

The project requirements are Jdk 1.7 or higher.

My installed version is

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

It looks like I have some version problem. I would appreciate if you could show me the problem.

```
javac 1.6.0_27
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the version of Java you're actually compiling with? How are you compiling, exactly?

Comment: You show `java -version`, but what about `**javac** -version`? In any event, this is a compile environment problem. (hypothesis: a 1.7 JRE but a 1.6 JDK)

Comment: try `Map<String, Double> simScoreTable = new HashMap<>();` as Map is super class

Comment: @KunalKrishna this doesn't matter; anyway, the position of the cursor in the error makes it clear that the diamond is the problem

Comment: can you provide the actual code(at least the line)where error is thrown/caught

Comment: @fge, javac 1.6.0_27, how can I update this?

Comment: See my answer for how to install it

Comment: did u also try 
`HashMap<String, Double> simScoreTable = new HashMap<String, Double>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using a 1.6 JDK but a 1.7 JRE. Since you are using ubuntu, try and see what this command gives:

```
dpkg --list|grep openjdk
```

If my reasoning is correct, you will have `openjdk-6-jdk` and `openjdk-7-jre`. If this is the case, try and:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Normally, JDK 7 has a higher priority than JDK 6 (see `update-alternatives`); so after install, you should have the correct compiler version. Check again with `javac -version`.